# Catch Mathematica warnings/errors without displaying them

Tags: warnings, wolfram-mathematica, try-catch

I have a problem involving NDSolve in Mathematica, which I run multiple times with different values of the parameters. For some of these values, the solution results in singularities and NDSolve warns with NDSolve::ndsz or other related warnings.

I would simply like to catch these warnings, suppress their display, and just keep track of the fact that a problem occurred for these particular values of the parameters. I thought of the following options (neither of which really do the trick):

1. I know I can determine whether a command has resulted in a warning or error by using `Check`. However, that will still display the warning. If I turn it off with `Off` the `Check` fails to report the warning too.
2. It is possible to stop NDSolve using the `EventLocator` method, so I could check for very large values of the function or its derivatives and stop evaluation in that case. However, in practice, this still produces warnings from time to time, presumably because the step size can sometimes be so large that the NDSolve warning triggers before my `Event` has taken place.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you wrap the `Check` with `Quiet` then I believe that everything should work as you want. For example, you can suppress the specific message `Power::indet`

```
In[1]:= Quiet[Check[0^0,err,Power::indet],Power::indet]
Out[1]= err
```

but other messages are still displayed

```
In[2]:= Quiet[Check[Sin[x,y],err,Power::indet],Power::indet]
During evaluation of In[2]:= Sin::argx: Sin called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>
Out[2]= Sin[x,y]
```

Comment: While Check does not seem to catch NDSolve::ndsz warnings, the hint about Quiet was very helpful.

Comment: @Kasper: Glad I could help. Can you give an example where `Check` fails to catch the `NDSolve` warning?

Answer (score 5):

Using Quiet and Check together works:

```
Quiet[Check[Table[1/Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi], \[Pi]}], $Failed]]
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see Simon's earlier answer coming in. Reminder to self: refresh before posting

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you wish to [redirect messages](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Messages.html)?  This is copied almost verbatim from that page.

```
stream = OpenWrite["msgtemp.txt"];

$Messages = {stream};

1/0

FilePrint["msgtemp.txt"]
```